# Number of elements of order 3 in $C_3 \times C_9$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

What is the number of elements of order 3 in the internal direct product $C_3 \times C_9$ of $C_3$ and $C_9$ where $C_i$ is the cyclic group of order $i$.

My work so far, let $(a,b) \in C_3 \times C_9$
Then $(a,b)^3=(a^3,b^3)$.

Case: $a$ is of order 3(2 such elements). Then $b$ is of order 1 or 3, of which there are 3 such elements. So there are $2*3=6$ options.

Case: $a$ has order 1, so is the identity element. Then $b$ must be of order $3$ of which there are two elements. So $2$ options in total. So this would give 8 elements. Is this correct and also is there a more succinct way of writing this?

Comment: You have asked enough questions here to know that you should show us your work and where you are stuck, so we can help where you need it rather than just telling you the answer.

Comment: How about now? @EthanBolker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.  Here are two slicker approaches to the problem:

- Count the number of elements whose order *divides* $3$.  This corresponds to elements of the form $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ have order $1$ or $3$.  There are three choices for each of $a$ and $b$, so this leads to $9$ elements.  Of these elements, exactly one is the identity, with order $1$, so there are $8$ of order $3$.
- The set of elements of $C_3\times C_9$ of order *dividing* $3$ forms a group (since the order of an element of an abelian group is the least common multiple of the orders of its factors).  Since the order of $C_3\times C_9$ is $27$, by Lagrange's theorem, the order of this subgroup is $1$, $3$, $9$, or $27$.  There are at least $4$ elements of order $3$ and there can't be $27$ since there are elements of order $9$.  Hence, the order of the group must be $9$.  Subtracting the identity gives $8$.  Note that the group of interest is isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3$.